# How to remove zoom on hover on product image in view page in Magento2?

Tags: magento-2.1, product-images, product-view, zoom

How to remove the zoom feature on hover on the product image in product view page? 

I have tried below code, but it is not working.

```
<var name="gallery">
    <var name="allowfullscreen">false</var> <!-- Turn on/off fullscreen (true/false) -->
</var>
<var name="magnifier">
   <var name="enabled">false</var> <!-- Turn on/off magnifier (true/false) -->
</var>
```